# Making a crystal material in Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

I'd like to make a crystal triangular pillar in Blender that looks like the example someone gave in response to a question like mine.

[image: the image in question]

I've tried to get it to look like this but just end up with it looking like this

[image: my go at it]

Since I do not have to privilige to comment yet I can't ask the creator how he/she did it. Can someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Is this is like a game of spot the difference? Only thing I see different is that you have the order of the last mix shader inverted compared to the example solution

Comment: But when I switch those around I get this

[link](https://i.imgur.com/Z1oOypP.png)

Comment: You may have inverted normals. Also, the example solution seems to have a bit more geometry on his crystals than yours, maybe a *Subsurf*mModifier, or perhaps a *Bevel*

Comment: Inverting the normals has indeed made a difference but what I'm looking for is the edges to be bright blue and the space in between to be almost completely see-trough, like the example picture. But the problem is that i can't get the space in between the edges to be more transparent.

Comment: Like I said above your crystals seem to have considerably less geometry compared to the example provided, either that or you have flat shading, as opposed to smooth shaded. It's impossible to know more from the images alone. This question is bordering on the *Too localized* category.

Comment: Oh wow. It indeed was flat shading. After setting it to smooth shading I got exactly the result I wanted. Thanks man

Comment: [Gemstone Material](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/KdDxx) here is a nice gemstone material you can adjust to your liking.
It also entails quite a bit of explaining.

Answer (score 2):

It eens to me that you should add a little more geometry, make sure the roughness value on your glass shader is the same as your examples and the main difference that I see is the lighting setup. The other person is using some sort of image texture as their light source. A very nice touch. Also, I suggest you turn up your samples so the image isnt so grainy. If you have any questions as to how you can do any of this jut ask

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should add more geometry, and your emission appears to be a little bit more on the turquoise side. Try lessening the green a bit, and adding some more facets.